# org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException, nested exception is java.sql.SQLException

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-security, crud

I am trying to build simple CRUD app with Spring framework and Spring security. There is a 'sign in' requirement where app authorise and authenticates user. I was able to sign in with hard coded values but when I tried getting users and passwords with JDBC and MySQLWorkbench, its giving this error:

`org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!`

I tried debugging in a test Class and it gave "connection successful"

```
package com.paras.springsecurity.demo.config;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;


public class TestApp {
    public static void main(String[]args){
          Connection con = null;
          try {
             con = DriverManager.
             getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_security_demo_plaintext?useSSL=false", "springstudent", "springstudent");
             System.out.println("Connection is successful !!!!!");
          } catch(Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
}
```

Now I am not able to understand what is the issue here when app and jdbc connections, password, and user is working

persistence-mysql.properties

```
#
# JDBC connection properties
#
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_security_demo_plaintext?useSSL=false
jdbc.user=springstudent
jdbc.password=springstudent

#
# Connection pool properties
#
connection.pool.initialPoolSize=5
connection.pool.minPoolSize=5
connection.pool.maxPoolSize=20
connection.pool.maxIdleTime=3000
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.paras</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>spring-security-demo</name>

    <properties>
        <springframework.version>5.2.8.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <springsecurity.version>5.3.4.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring MVC support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet, JSP and JSTL support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- to compensate for java 9+ not including jaxb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Spring security dependency -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Add support for spring security Taglib support -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!--  Add mysql and c3p0 support -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.45</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
                <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
            
    </dependencies>

    <!-- TO DO: Add support for Maven WAR Plugin -->
    <build>
        <finalName>spring-security-demo</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <!-- Add maven coordinates(GAV) for: maven-war-plugin -->
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.1</version>                    
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

Jdbc configuration file - DemoAppConfig.java

```
package com.paras.springsecurity.demo.config;

import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.paras.springsecurity.demo")
@PropertySource("classpath:persistence-mysql.properties")
public class DemoAppConfig {
    //set up a var to hold the projects
    
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    //env will hold data read from proprties file
    //set up a logger
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
    
    //define a bean for viewResolver
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
    
    //define a bean for our security datasource
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource securityDataSource() {
        //create a connection pool
        ComboPooledDataSource securityDataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        //set the jdbc driver class
        try {
            securityDataSource.setDriverClass(env.getProperty("jdbc.driver"));
        } catch (PropertyVetoException exc) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exc);
        }
        //log the connection props
        logger.info(">>>>> jdbc.url " + env.getProperty("jdbc.url")); 
        logger.info(">>>>> jdbc.user " + env.getProperty("jdbc.user")); 

        
        //set database connection props
        securityDataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        securityDataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        securityDataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));

        //set connection pool props
    
        securityDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.initialPoolSize"));
        securityDataSource.setMinPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.minPoolSize"));
        securityDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxPoolSize"));
        securityDataSource.setMaxIdleTime(getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxIdleTime"));
        
        return securityDataSource;
    }
    
    //helper method to read environment property and convert to int
    
    private int getIntProperty(String propName) {
        String propVal = env.getProperty(propName);
        int intPropVal = Integer.parseInt(propVal);
        return intPropVal;
    }
    
}
```

Calling Spring Security Data Source in the class - DemoSecurityConfig.java

```
package com.paras.springsecurity.demo.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class DemoSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    //add a reference  to our security source
    @Autowired
    private DataSource securityDataSource;
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(securityDataSource);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
        .antMatchers("/leaders/**").hasRole("MANAGER")
        .antMatchers("/systems/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/showMyLoginPage")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser").permitAll().and().logout().permitAll().and().exceptionHandling().
        accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the issue

```
//set database connection props
        securityDataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        securityDataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        securityDataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
```

You are using setJdbcUrl for everything
It should be something like

```
//set database connection props
        securityDataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        securityDataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        securityDataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
```